# Comparing two csv files which has very less common columns values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Problem statement:
I've two csv files with row values in column_1,column_2,column_4_column_5 same in both the csv files.

file1.csv

```
(**column_1**,**column_2**,column_3,**column_4**,**column_5**,column_6,column_7) -> Header
(**Joe**,**24**,USA,**college_1**,**MBA**,1year,gradeA)
(Maddy,26,UK,college_2,MS,2year,gradeB)
```

file2.csv

```
(**column_1**,**column_2**,column_3,**column_4**,**column_5**,column_6,column_7) -> Header
(**Joe**,**24**,IND,**college_1**,**MBA**,4year,gradeB)
(**Maddy**,**26**,UK,college_2,MS,2year,gradeB)
(Sandy,30,UK,college_3,DR,2year,gradeA)
```

I would like to compare these two files in such a manner that if the row values seen in column_1,column_2,column_4_column_5 are same then consider that the entire row is same in both the files. For example,

file1.csv

(**column_1**,**column_2**,column_3,**column_4**,**column_5**,column_6,column_7) -> Header
(**Joe**,**24**,USA,**college_1**,**MBA**,1year,gradeA)

file2.csv

(**column_1**,**column_2**,column_3,**column_4**,**column_5**,column_6,column_7) -> Header
(**Joe**,**24**,IND,**college_1**,**MBA**,4year,gradeB)

Here we can see that, there is a single row in both the files. Column values seen in **column_1,column_2,column_4,column_5** are similar and column_3,column_6,column_7 are different. Inspite of this, consider that the row is similar.

So in this case if I'm comparing file1.csv and file2.csv my output file will something like this.

output.csv

```
(**column_1**,**column_2**,column_3,**column_4**,**column_5**,column_6,column_7) -> Header
(Sandy,30,UK,college_3,DR,2year,gradeA)
```

I've provided the code which I created but it's not working properly.

```
file1 = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv')   
    file2 = pd.read_csv('file_2.csv') 

    # Define the columns to use for comparison
    compare_cols = ['column_1','column_2','column_4','column_5']

    # Filter file2 to only include rows that are not in file1
    comparison_new = file2[~file2[compare_cols].isin(file1[compare_cols].to_dict('l')).all(1)]

    # Write the new rows to a new CSV file
    try:
        comparison_new.to_csv("latest_comparison.csv", index=False)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```